# Grafana not displaying data from Elasticsearch datasource

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I am trying to set up a very simple timeseries in elasticsearch to display in grafana. I just want an index that has documents with a `ts` field and a `count_rejected` field. I've got elasticsearch and graphana up and running, and I've added an elasticsearch datastore. So far so good. I set up the query in the attached image, and as you can see there is a data point in the response. However the graph shows "No data points". How is it that my query has data but the graph is blank?

[image: Request to Elasticsearch]

Answer (score 0):

I was not grouping my data properly. I am not sure why graphana wasn't displaying any data, but I was able to figure out how to make it work.[image]